# How does one increment/update integer value of an XML Attribute in C# (XAttribute)?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, xattribute

**TL;DR**: If I have an `XAttribute` of `NumFruits` in an `XElement`, how can I increment/update the value from 0 to 1,2,3... ?

**The issue:**

When I attempt to increment the XAttribute like so:

```
basket.Attribute("numFruits").Value += 1
```

the result for `numFruits` will be `numFruits = 01` (since 0 was the initial value), when the intended result was supposed to be `numFruits = 1`

Global variables that are added at the end of the parsing is not desired as there can be many baskets.

**Explanation:**

In C# Linq to XML, one can add `XAttributes` to an `XElement` like so.

`XElement basket = new XElement("Marys_Basket", new XAttribute("NumFruits", 0);`

where in the example we use `NumFruits` `XAttribute` as a counter to keep track of number of fruits in the `XDocument`.

As I interate through a list of (for example) Fruit objects that each also have a `basket_owner` property, I serialize all those objects to XML manually by creating or adding to `XElements` which in this example would be the owners.

As the list of fruits is not fixed, I have to add Fruit elements to the XElement and update the `XAttribute` by first checking if the owner element exists (I've done this with LINQ queries and checking if they are null) and then adding the Fruit XElement as a child, yielding something like so:

```
<Root>
  <Marys_basket numFruits=2>
     <Fruit name="Mango"/>
     <Fruit name="Papaya"/>
  </Marys_basket>
  <Jons_basket numFruits=0 />
  <Bobs_basket numFruits=1> 
     <Fruit name="Apple"/>
  </Bobs_basket>
</Root>
```

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821750/increment-a-xml-with-c-sharp) on how to increment an XML Element (in this case XElement), but not an XAttribute. And [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053577/update-xattribute-value-where-xattribute-name-x) but not specifically to increasing a value.

I've found one method (posted as an answer) and would like to explore a more robust way to do so. As my program does this multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way of doing it I've found so far:

`basket.FirstAttribute.SetValue(  Int32.Parse(  basket.FirstAttribute.Value ) + 1);`

Note that `basket.Attribute("numFruits")` can also be used.

What that does is grab the attribute we want and set the value by first parsing the existing value as an `Integer` and then increment the value by 1. This is because values set as XAttributes are saved/retrieved as strings.

The reason that doing `basket.Attribute("numFruits") += 1` yields 01 instead of 1 or 11 instead of 2 when attempting to increment is that Attribute values are stored as strings, and doing a += operation becomes a string concatenation object.

Comment: Now that you know that attribute values are strings, you may want to rethink the concept of modifying your XDocument in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Would be even shorter if you cast the `XAttribute` to `int` directly :

```
basket.FirstAttribute.SetValue((int)basket.FirstAttribute + 1);
```

Just like `XElement`, `XAttribute` also has some [explicit conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) predefined.

---

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vT2RcB) * :

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<Root>
  <Marys_basket numFruits=""2"">
     <Fruit name=""Mango""/>
     <Fruit name=""Papaya""/>
  </Marys_basket>
  <Jons_basket numFruits=""0"" />
  <Bobs_basket numFruits=""1""> 
     <Fruit name=""Apple""/>
  </Bobs_basket>
</Root>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XElement basket = doc.Root.Element("Marys_basket");
        basket.FirstAttribute.SetValue((int)basket.FirstAttribute + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
    }
}
```

*: <sub>Mainly for future visitor, as I believe OP already know about the rest</sub>