# XmlSerializer - Iterating over branches

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have an xml supplied by an external source. I have no say in their design or function.

I can reach the initial branch and read the values as needed. I fear editing as I can't access any of the other branches, and if I start tampering with the main branch I could end up removing any other branch besides the one I can deal with.

My main branch looks as:
Container \ Object \ Object \ List \ Object \ Property

as in

```
<Container>
  <Object>
    <Object>
      <List>
        <Object>
          <Property>
```

As the data I need to Read and Update, are attributes in `<Property>`. I have an IntOrderID, FirstName, LastName I'm working with.

What I need is the ability to Read and Update an OrderID, which are located in different branches under:

Container \ Object \ Object(*) \ List \ Object \ Property

I have n branches under Object(*) which are having a `<Property>` with attribute name=OrderID. Value wise then IntOrderID and OrderID are precisely the same value. Previously I've used a linq read and replace function to do my work. That solution is coming up short.

For my container object I have:
EDIT: 18/09/23 I may have had an aha moment.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Object")]
public class Object
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "List")]
    public List List { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Object")]
    public Object ObjectLvl2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Object")]
    public List<ObjectBranch> ObjectBranch { get; set; }  // TODO: There are n branches from this point.

    public Object() { }
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ObjectBranch")]
public class ObjectBranch
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "List")]
    public List List { get; set; }

    public ObjectBranch() { }
}
```

Edit:
I'm using a wrapper to access the serializer, within that I'm using a Discover() to read the values as needed:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Discover the attributes from the xml file.
> /// </summary>
> public void Discover()
> {
>     foreach (var item in Container.ObjectLvl1.ObjectLvl2.List.ObjectLvl3.Property)
>     {
>         switch (item.Name)
>         {
>             case "IntOrderID":
>                 IntOrderID = item.Value;
>                 break;
>             case "FirstName":
>                 FirstName = item.Value;
>                 break;
>             case "LastName":
>                 LastName = item.Value;
>                 break;
>             case "OrderID":
>                 OrderID = item.Value;
>                 break;
>             default:
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

EDIT 05/10/23

My solution came down to

```
List<XElement> elementOID = xml.Descendants("Property")
    .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "OrderID")
    .ToList();

foreach (var orderID in elementOID)
{
   orderID.Attribute("value").Value = item.Value;
}
```

Where item refers to a dictionary where I keep each of the replacement values I needed (IntOrderID, Firstname, Lastname, OrderID).

Notes taken from - [Update XAttribute Value where XAttribute Name = X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053577/update-xattribute-value-where-xattribute-name-x)

Comment: I'm afraid that few people will understand your explanation. Let's try to figure it out. You have a large complex XML that you want to deserialize, then edit part of the data and serialize again. Right?

Comment: If you can't get a strict C# class structure, then it's probably better not to use deserialization using XmlSerializer. I would try LINQ: XDocument/XElement. Possibly using XPath.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderPetrov for pointing me in the direction of XDocument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach (var item in replacements)
    {
        switch (item.Key)
        {
            case Patient.PropertyNames.IntOrderID:
                // IntOrderID
                var elementIOID = xml.Descendants("Property")
                    .Single(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "IntOrderID");
                elementIOID.Attribute("value").Value = item.Value;
                break;
            case Patient.PropertyNames.Patient_FirstName:
                // Firstname, repeated code.
                break;
            case Patient.PropertyNames.Patient_LastName:
                // Lastname, repeated code.
                break;
            case Patient.PropertyNames.OrderID:
                // OrderID
                List<XElement> elementOIDs = xml.Descendants("Property")
                    .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "OrderID")
                    .ToList();

                foreach (var orderID in elementOIDs)
                {
                    orderID.Attribute("value").Value = item.Value;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```